# Why is PhpStorm making these variables dark red?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: Variables in red]

Is it because they are implicit? How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the color for function/method parameters is defined in the color scheme.

You can change it to match your preferences. Open Settings, go to Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> PHP and choose in the list on the right side "Functions and Methods -> Parameter". On the right-hand side of the window there are controls to change the color.

Comment: Pretty obvious, but I really thought my dark themes was all broken, very annoying...